# .getId of a folder just created by script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am learning Google Script and making a few scripts to see what is possible and i wanted to make a folder and make a file in it or add/more other items to it.  But i am confused how to return the id of the new folder and write to that id.  I tried the getId function with no luck.
Here is where i am at:

```
function getStaticInfo_() {
  var staticInfo = {
    rezin8JobFolderSystemId: 'FolderID 1',  
    folderConfig1: 'TestClient#4'
  }       
  return staticInfo;
}


function CreateFolderAndSub() {
  //Get the static info.
  var static = getStaticInfo_();     
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(static.rezin8JobFolderSystemId);      

  destination.createFolder(static.folderConfig1);

  var nextFolder1GetId = DriveApp.openFoldersByName(static.folderConfig1);
//  var nextFolder1Id = DriveApp.getFolderById(nextFolder1GetId);
  var nextFolder1Id = nextFolder1GetId.getId;

//  var body1 = formObject.sourceFolder;                    
//  var body2 = formObject.clientType;
//  var body3 = formObject.newProjectName;
//  var body4 = formObject.newClientName;
  var body5 = nextFolder1Id;
  var body = Logger.getLog();
  destination.createFile('Log','<b>sourceFolder = ' +body1 + '  END  ' + '<b>clientType = ' +body2 + '  END  </b>' + '<b>newProjectName = ' +body3 + '  END  </b>' + '<b>newClientName = ' +body4 + ' END  </b>' + '<b>nextFolder1Id = ' +body5 + ' END  </b>', MimeType.HTML);

}
```

If anyone can give me any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Your create folder function will return created new folder `destination.createFolder`. so you can get the folder id like,

```
var nextFolder1 = destination.createFolder(static.folderConfig1);   
var nextFolder1Id = nextFolder1.getId();
```

Read more from here - [createFolder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app?hl=en#createFolder(String))

Since `createFolder` returns new folder, you can create new file on it;

```
nextFolder1.createFile('Log','<b>sourceFolder = ' +body1 + '  END  ' + '<b>clientType = ' +body2 + '  END  </b>' + '<b>newProjectName = ' +body3 + '  END  </b>' + '<b>newClientName = ' +body4 + ' END  </b>' + '<b>nextFolder1Id = ' +body5 + ' END  </b>', MimeType.HTML);
```

Altogether,

```
function CreateFolderAndSub() {
  //Get the static info.
  var static = getStaticInfo_();     
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(static.rezin8JobFolderSystemId);      

  var nextFolder1 = destination.createFolder(static.folderConfig1);

  //var nextFolder1GetId = DriveApp.openFoldersByName(static.folderConfig1);

  var nextFolder1Id = nextFolder1.getId();

  var body1 = 'val1';//formObject.sourceFolder;                    
  var body2 = 'val2';//formObject.clientType;
  var body3 = 'val3';//formObject.newProjectName;
  var body4 = 'val4';//formObject.newClientName;
  var body5 = nextFolder1Id;
  var body = Logger.getLog();
  nextFolder1.createFile('Log','<b>sourceFolder = ' +body1 + '  END  ' + '<b>clientType = ' +body2 + '  END  </b>' + '<b>newProjectName = ' +body3 + '  END  </b>' + '<b>newClientName = ' +body4 + ' END  </b>' + '<b>nextFolder1Id = ' +body5 + ' END  </b>', MimeType.HTML);

}
```